# Program and run time determination

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, runtime, pseudocode

Given the following pseudo code

```
D(A) // A is an array of numbers
U_Size = 1
for i=2 to length(A)
   U=?
   for j=1 to U_Size
      if A[j]=A[i]
        then U = FALSE
            j = U_size
   if U = TRUE
     then U_Size = U_Size + 1
        A[U_Size]=A[i]
return U_Size
```

1. *What will be the best opton to replace the "?" in line 4? ( `U=?` )

   and what exactly does this program do - **Answered***
2. How should I determine the run-time & space complexity of this program

> MY ANSWER: In line 4, I initialized U -> `U = TRUE` and figured that the program arranges all of the different elements of the array in the beginning of the arry and returns the amount of different elements
> **The Question remained unanswered is**: How should I determine the run-time & space complexity of this program (2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not familiar with the [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#:%7E:text=Big%20O%20notation%20is%20a,a%20particular%20value%20or%20infinity.&text=A%20description%20of%20a%20function,growth%20rate%20of%20the%20function.), I would suggest to read about it because in computer science we use that to represent the time and space complexity.

Let the length of input array is `n`.
The time complexity of this code will be **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** in the worst-case and the worst-case occurs for an array of all distinct numbers. For an input array of all distinct numbers, the if condition `if A[j] = A[i]` is always false, so the inner looop of `j` loops from `1` to `U_size` for every `i` and `U_size` is increased by `1` everytime.
If it is still not clear then you can understand it using math for an array of all distinct numbers.

For `i = 2`, and `U_size = 1`, the inner loop of `j` runs from `1 to 1` i.e 1 time.
For `i = 3`, and `U_size = 2`, the inner loop of `j` runs from `1 to 2` i.e 2 times.
For `i = 4`, and `U_size = 3`, the inner loop of `j` runs from `1 to 3` i.e 3 times.
For `i = 5`, and `U_size = 4`, the inner loop of `j` runs from `1 to 4` i.e 4 times.
.
.
.
.
.
For `i = n (length of array A)`, and `U_size = n-1`, the inner loop of `j` runs from `1 to n-1` i.e n-1 times.

So, if you sum up the running times for all the iterations of i,
`1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + n-1`, you get `n*(n-1)/2` which is ~ **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**.

---

Now, space complexity. You have used the array `A` itself for assigning after the `j` loop. If you do not take into account the input array for reporting space, then you get **O(1)** as space complexity.

If you store a separate array for assigning the element i.e `A[U_Size]=A[i]` or you consider the input array itself for space, then you would say space complexity as **O(n)**.